ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Sidekiq::Sequence::Record with 'id'
I'm using the Sidekiq-sequence Gem to run sidekiq jobs in a sequence instead of all at once.
I'm getting this warning in my Sidekiq retry queue and not real sure what to do about them and if they are causing any issues or not?
The impact is almost insignificant, but I would still like to know what's going on. Out of roughly 3.5 million jobs run there are 22 retries with these errors. So 99.999% are running perfectly.
Anyone seen this before? Anything to do about these and then are they causing any real impact or is the job simply being retried with a new record?

Please post some code as well as the stacktrace for the error

Could you share some code that from where you fire the sidekiq job?
